# Show convergence of series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k} $ converges. My idea is that, for any integer $k \ge 1 $, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{k!}{k^k}
&= \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{2}{k}\cdots\frac{k-2}{k}\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot\frac{k}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{2}{k}\cdots\frac{k-2}{k}\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{2}{k}\cdots\cdot\frac{k-2}{k} \\
&\qquad \vdots \\
&\leq \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{2}{k}
 = \frac{2}{k^2}
\end{align*}

That is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{k^2} $$

And since right-hand side of the inequality is finite, so is left-hand side and therefore the series is convergent.

However, I dont find this way of solving the assignment elegant and I believe there is a cleaner way. Appreciates all help I can get.

Comment: It's actually pretty elegant to me.

Comment: Yeah, it is a nice idea that is simply stated. It is good.

Comment: This is a good argument. One remark for the details: we should assume $k\geq 2$ for your reduction (although you do still have the inequality for $k=1$).

Comment: Linking [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619509).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the root test together with the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean (GM-AM):

$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{k!}{k^k}}= \frac{\sqrt[k]{k!}}{k}\stackrel{GM-AM}{\leq}\frac{\frac{k(k+1)}{2k}}{k}=\frac{k+1}{2k}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac 12 <1$$

Comment: +1 nice use of the root test

Answer (score 6):

You can apply the Ratio Test and use $\displaystyle{\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k=e}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another elementary solution. Using the inequality $x(a-x) \leq \frac{a^2}{4}$ for $0 \leq x \leq a$, we get

$$ \frac{k!}{k^k} = \frac{(k-1)!}{k^{k-1}} = \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\sqrt{j(k-j)}}{k} \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}. $$

Therefore the series converges by the Direct Comparison Test.

Comment: Almost correct. It should be $1/2^{k-1}$. Still converges.

Comment: @martycohen My silly, thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\mathrm{e}^k  = 1 + k +  \ldots  + \frac{{k^k }}{{k!}} +  \ldots  \geq \frac{{k^k }}{{k!}},
$$
we have
$$
\frac{{k!}}{{k^k }} \leq \mathrm{e}^{ - k} .
$$
Thus, $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{k!}}{{k^k }}}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\mathrm{e}^{ - k} }  = \frac{1}{{\mathrm{e} - 1}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Stirling's formula for the asymptotics of $k!$ as $k\to\infty$ to bound it:
$$k! = \mathcal{O}\left(k^{k+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-k}\right),$$
which you can derive from a Laplace-type expansion of $k!=\int_0^\infty e^{k \log x} e^{-x} \,dx$ for large $k$. Hence, your summand is $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{k}\,e^{-k}\right)$, meaning that its sum over $\mathbb{N}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n k}{n^n}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (k/n)\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} ((n-k)/n)\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-k/n)\\
g(n)
&=\ln(f(n))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \ln(1-k/n)\\
&<\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} -k/n
\qquad \ln(1-x) < -x\\
&=-\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2n}\\
&=-\dfrac{n-1}{2}\\
&=\dfrac12=\dfrac{n}{2}\\
\text{so}\\
f(n)
&\le e^{-(n-1)/2}\\
&=e^{1/2}(e^{-1/2})^n\\
\text{so}\\
\end{array}
$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)
\le \dfrac{e^{1/2}}{1-e^{-1/2}}
$.