# Use the ratio test to determine if the following series converges or diverges: $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k!}{k^{k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Use the ratio test to determine if the following series converges or diverges:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^{k}}
\end{align*}$$

Trying to solve this problem, used algebra to simplify to  $\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k},$ but from there is goes off the tracks.

Comment: What have you tried? The question tells you exactly how to do it. Do you know what the ratio test is? Do you know what $k!$ means?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I see the editor removed a little show of work on your part. I will try to restore that.

Comment: $$
\frac{{k^k }}{{(k + 1)^k }} = \frac{1}{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)^k }} \to \frac{1}{{\rm e}}
$$

Comment: Don't simplify $\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k}$.  Find its limit.  You know some methods for limits of indeterminate forms, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619509/does-sum-k-1-infty-frackkk-converge)

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor's theorem: $\log(1-x) = -x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$.

As $k \to \infty$,
$$
\log \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} = k \log\frac{k}{(k+1)}
=k\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
=k\left(-\frac{1}{k+1}+o(1/k)\right) = \frac{-k}{k+1}+o(1) .
$$
So
$$
\log \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} \to -1 ,
\\ \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} \to e^{-1} .
$$

Comment: So you do not define $\mathrm{e}$ to be the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$.

Comment: @Gary ... Some texts may do that...  I refer to Spivak, where $\log$ is defined by $$\log x = \int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$$ and $e$ is defined by $$\log(e)=1$$ and $e^x$ is the inverse of $\log x$.

Comment: The solution is an overkill. Usually calculus textbooks cover the differential calculus,  the Taylor expansions, of $\log (1+x)$ in particular, long after studying the limit $(1+k^{-1})^k.$ Another overkill solution can apply the Stirling formula and  the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k$ equal $\frac{k!}{k^k}$.

Then we have,

$$\left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| = \frac{\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}}{\frac{k!}{k^k}} = k\cdot \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \frac{k^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$$

$$= \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}}\right)^{k+1} = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+1}} \to \frac{1}{e} < 1.$$

Therefore the series

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}{a_k}$$

converges.